# How to show only records that have ocurred after an events - . Redshift/Postgresql -

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

This may sound a little convoluted, so please bear with me.

I have 2 tables.

One is my sales which has columns:

> ordernumber,  storenumber,  customerid,  ordervalue,  purchasedate

The other is my marketing events table which has many columns, but I am using:

> eventtype,subscriberkey and eventdate

I have union the tables this is their current structure

> marketing.eventtype = sales.ordernumber, marketing.subscriberkey =sales.customerid and sales.purchasedate = marketing.eventdate. Order value and store number are null if empty.

I only want to show the sales that have come directly after a eventtype or multiple event type - so a sale is shown as the last record after the list is ordered by customerid/subscriberid.

I also want to limit it to any marketing events between a certain date and give a window of conversion in days for the sale.

```
    SELECT ordernumber, 
       storenumber, 
       customerid, 
       ordervalue, 
       purchasedate FROM   table.sales oh 
WHERE  purchasedate > '2016-01-16' 
       AND purchasedate < '2016-01-24' 
       AND ordervalue > 0 
       AND customerid IN (SELECT subscriberkey 
                          FROM   table.marketing 
                          WHERE  eventtype = 'Open' 
                                 AND eventdate < '2016-01-19' 
                                 AND eventdate > '2016-01-15') 
UNION 
SELECT eventtype     AS ordernumber, 
       NULL          AS storenumber, 
       subscriberkey AS customerid, 
       NULL          AS ordervalue, 
       eventdate     AS purchasedate 
FROM   table.marketing
WHERE  eventtype = 'Open' 
       AND eventdate < '2016-01-19' 
       AND eventdate > '2016-01-15' 
       AND subscriberkey IN (SELECT customerid 
                             FROM   table.sales oh 
                             WHERE  purchasedate > '2016-01-16' 
                                    AND purchasedate < '2016-01-24'
                ) 
ORDER  BY customerid, 
          purchasedate ASC
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to compare "natural sales" and the marketing uplift? Only counting sales after an event will give a biased image.

Comment: appreciate the comment - that will be part of it, however not for this piece of work

Comment: this is more to see attribution than anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the result of the query you have "events" (it's going to be used as a subquery). Then showing only the sales which came after a marketing event can be done via [a window function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LEAD.html).

1. First, we copy the data from following row in the previous row. Ordered in reverse, we copy marketing data into sales row:

   `SELECT LEAD(events.ordernumber, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY purchasedate desc) as following_ordernumber, 
   LEAD(events.purchasedate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY purchasedate desc) as following_purchasedate`

   By grouping by customer we are isolating a group of customer events, and by ordering in reverse by date, we can use LEAD (only works forward) to extract the marketing data, and copy it into the sales rows. Let's call this new query "enriched_sales".
2. Then, we filter out everything but sales events:

   `WHERE enriched_sales.ordernumber != 'Open' and enriched_sales.following_ordernumber = 'Open'`

   In reverse order, we want sales rows which are immediately followed by marketing rows. After copying data from such marketing rows, ordernumber of the sales row would not be 'Open', while copied value will be 'Open'.
3. Finally, we use the dates to compute the conversion window:

   `SELECT datediff(days, following_purchasedate, purchasedate) ...`

If you post the table definitions and input/output data I can produce the whole query, but hopefully you get the idea.